# How to get data(real time location and heart rate ) from paired apple watch and use it in my iOS app?

Tags: ios, xcode, watch

I'm developing an app for alzheimer's people to keep track of their location and their heart rate , basically the patient will be wearing an apple watch 3.0 that paired to the caregiver's iPhone .

my app will be running on caregiver's iPhone , I need to get access to heart rate and location in near real time from the watch EVEN if the watch screen is turned off .

How can I do that ?